# Are "Waterproofing Primer" and "Grout Sealer" the same?

Tags: bathroom, tile, grout

As I'm getting close to end of bathroom renovation, hardware store recommends me to purchase 'grout sealer' to finish off new layered grout. When I test it out, I found out it is very similar to 'waterproofing primer' I used pre-laying tiles and I have plenty of that left over. If they are the same, then I might return the 'grout sealer' as it is unecessary.

The 2 specific product I'm looking at are:

Primer: [Gripset Betta](http://www.gripsetbetta.com/product.php?id=1)

Grout Sealer: [Tecniseal Silicone Sealant](http://www.dta-aus.com.au/categories/ta/gs/GS02) also seen on page 39 of this [PDF](http://www.tilefactoryoutlet.com.au/PDF/DTA%20Tools%20&%20Accessories%20Catalogue.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

I'd doubt that the primer could be used effectively as a grout sealer.  The primer is designed (in part) to mix in with another liquid to aid in waterproofing.  Grout sealer is designed to soak into dry grout to make aid in waterproofing.

Grout sealer is meant to be re-applied once a year (I don't know how many people actually do that).

If it works for you, then its fine.  but, if you get a leak into the grout and under the tile you risk water stains and mould.